# Adding a slice function to a string

Tags: javascript, regex, hashtag

Can someone explain to me how the slice function is working on the following example? (It is a Hashtag generator)

```js
function generateHashtag(str) {
  if (str.length >= 140 || str == "") {
    return false;
  } else {
    str = str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    let capEachWord = (str) => str.trim().split(' ')
      .map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)).join('');
    let HashtagIt = (str) => '#' + str;

    return HashtagIt(capEachWord(str));
  }

}

console.log(generateHashtag("String String"))
```

Comment: [MDN: `String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) -> _"The `slice()` method extracts a section of a string and returns it as a new string, without modifying the original string."_

Comment: `substring(1)` would do the same thing and be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `slice` method can be used for an `Array` or a `String` variable. The intention of `slice` method is to slice out some part of the data.

For example, if I have a string

```
let word = 'India';
```

And I want to extract `dia` from it, we can do it using -

```
let dia = word.slice(2); //output > dia,
```

This will slice the string from index `2` to end of the string.

If we want to slice the middle part of the string then we can do something like -

```
let di = word.slice(2, 4); //output > di
```

The same way we can process Array as well.